# remove brackets from nested list

Tags: python

I have a nested list that looks like this

```
[[[0]],
[[2], [1]],
[[3]],
[[4]],
[[5]],
[[6]],
[[7]],
[[8]],
[[9, 10]],
[[11]],
[[13], [12]]]
```

I want to simplify it into not flatten everything

```
[[0], [2], [1],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9,10],[11],[13],[12]]
```

simplify the nested list.

Comment: Where do you get this input (maybe you need to fix it there?)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: No I don't have access to the code that provides this output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten an irregular (arbitrarily nested) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-arbitrarily-nested-list-of-lists)

Comment: No I don't want to flatten everything, I still need to keep [9,10]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) The approved solution gave me your expected output. (the list comprehension one)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Looking at the specification, I see that you want to "make a flat list (of lists) out of a list of lists (of lists)". Hence that is the correct canonical duplicate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is a variation of "flattening" of the arrays.  here's an example solution for this:

```
nested_list = [[[0]],
[[2], [1]],
[[3]],
[[4]],
[[5]],
[[6]],
[[7]],
[[8]],
[[9, 10]],
[[11]],
[[13], [12]]]

simplified_list = []
for sub_list in nested_list:
    for item in sub_list:
        simplified_list.extend([item])

print(simplified_list)
```

it generates the output: `[[0], [2], [1], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9, 10], [11], [13], [12]]`

Answer (score 0):

Use (my_list is the original):

```
flat = [item for sublist in my_list for item in sublist]
print(flat)
```